# Spring Cloud Config: See other Application's properties?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I"m trying to setup a microservice system that uses Spring Cloud Config and Eureka. I would like to be able to see properties set in other applications' properties file (specifically the port number of Eureka).

Files in Spring Cloud Config git repository:

bootstrap.yml

```
  eureka:
    client:
      service-url:
        default-zone: http://localhost:9000
```

eureka-server.yml

```
  server:
    port: 9000
```

I would like for every service to know where Eureka is and this setup works fine, but if I were to change the port of eureka there would be two or more locations where I would need to change it. Is there a way to reference a value in another config file? so bootstrap.yml would in theory look something like this:

```
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      default-zone: http://localhost:${eureka-service.server.port}/
```

Comment: Not really a way to do that. Something has to be well known to bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

All your apps will either need to know the location of the eureka, or cloud config server, probably the easiest is to have the cloud config setup in the bootstrap, then grab the eureka location from cloud conifg. Any application can access the properties there so you can have common properties in the cloud config . One of which can be the port of eureka so there will only be one place eurekas port is defined.

IMO eureka may have its days numbered, amazon's application load balancer is superior to eureka and cloud formation will replace things like spring cloud config, but they were great projects to get people thinking about these things.

If your not in the cloud then sprint cloud is still a great solution however.